# ValueError: Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. Got array with shape

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, valueerror

I am getting this error, but do not know why.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\PycharmProjects\LeNet\LeNet.py", line 134, in <module>
    train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(704, 227, 227))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 36070300 into shape (704,227,227)
```

Below is the line that is causing the error message.

```
#Import the packages
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Image Data Augmentation
train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)
val_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)
test_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)

# Fitting the augmentation defined above to the data
train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(704, 227, 227))
val_generator.fit(x_val.reshape(704, 227, 227))
test_generator.fit(xtest.reshape(704, 227, 227))
```

UPDATE:
I modified the code to the following:

```
# Fitting the augmentation defined above to the data
train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(704, 227, 227))
val_generator.fit(x_val.reshape(704, 227, 227))
test_generator.fit(xtest.reshape(704, 227, 227))
```

and now getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\PycharmProjects\LeNet\LeNet.py", line 136, in <module>
    val_generator.fit(x_val.reshape(704, 227, 227))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4946784 into shape (704,227,227)
```

So I then removed the `704` and left the `-1` as shown below

```
# Fitting the augmentation defined above to the data
train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(-1, 227, 227))
val_generator.fit(x_val.reshape(-1, 227, 227))
test_generator.fit(xtest.reshape(-1, 227, 227))
```

but I then get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\PycharmProjects\LeNet\LeNet.py", line 135, in <module>
    train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(-1, 227, 227))
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\image_data_generator.py", line 935, in fit
    raise ValueError('Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. '
ValueError: Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. Got array with shape: (704, 227, 227)
```

Comment: `704*227*227 = 36_276_413` != `36_070_300`, Is 704 count of images?

Comment: @I'mahdi - which is I use -1 instead of 704 to indicate that the value shall be computed automatically, right?

Comment: @I'mahdi - 800 is the number of images in the training set, but after validation it goes down to 704.

Comment: Because I ask: `Is 704 count of images?` was for this purpose. You don't need to pass num of samples (here num of images). you need to set batch_size.

Comment: So change the batch size? or switch the num of samples to batch size?

Comment: What is `input_shape` of your model?

Comment: @I'mahdi - input_shape=(227, 227, 3)))

Comment: Do you solve your problem? what is the shape of your `xtrain`? You can get this with `print(xtrain.shape)` or your images `rgb` or `grayscale`?

Comment: @I'mahdi - ----- Dimension of LFW Dataset -----
The shape of the training image: (800, 227, 227)
The shape of testing image:  (100, 227, 227)
Shape of a single image:  (227, 227)

Comment: My images are populated from LFW and they are the aligned greyscale images.

Comment: can you try this : `train_generator.fit(xtrain[...,None])` & `val_generator.fit(x_val[...,None])` &`test_generator.fit(xtest[...,None])`

Comment: @I'mahdi - made the changes you suggested and got the following error message

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: I think you make mistake in using `ImageDataGenerator` after `ImageDataGenerator` you need use `flow` then use `fit`. You can read [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow) a  good example.

Comment: It works great with FERET dataset, so I don't think its the flow